# Use JS to Trigger Click on File Input

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to click on a `div` and trigger a file input window. Here's what I currently have:

```
<div id="loadInterval" onclick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click();">
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" value='C:\fakepath' style="display: none;" />
</div>
```

The above properly works, but now I'd like to add some logic between when the `div` is clicked and when the `file input` gets trigged. I'm running into trouble when I try to have a listener for `#loadInterval` being clicked. The listener appropriately works, and I can run any logic I want, but then I'm unable to properly trigger the `file input`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `<input type="file">` automatically pops open the file upload window when you click on the corresponding button. Are you trying to hide this button until the *parent* div is clicked on? Or are you trying to automatically pop open the file uploader when a different div is clicked on?

Comment: @Obsidian Age - I'm trying to completely hide the file input button (#fileInput) and trigger the input action when clicking its parent div (#loadInterval). That part currently works. I'm now trying to add some additional logic that determines whether or not the input window should pop up (after clicking the parent div).